# How to supply proper icon when a web page is pinned to Windows taskbar via Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

In some occasions, a favicon can show up on Windows taskbar via Chrome, for instance:

1. when a user clicks chrome menu -> More tools -> Create shortcut -> Open as window.
2. when a Chrome Extension calls `window.chrome.create({ type: popup })`.

My question is, how should I supply a good icon when this happens? How big is the resolution?

In case 1, my site has a favicon with `<link rel="icon" href="favicon.png">`, but it doesn't get used by windows automatically.

In case 2, in my extension `manifest.json`, I supplied multiple resolutions like this:

```
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/icon_16.png",
    "32": "images/icon_32.png",
    "48": "images/icon_48.png",
    "64": "images/icon_64.png",
    "96": "images/icon_96.png",
    "128": "images/icon_128.png"
  },
```

but it seems the 48x48 version gets used, and the resolution is not high enough, especially on scaled monitors.

Thanks!

Comment: It's most likely a bug/deficiency in Chrome. Consider reporting on https://crbug.com.